# Cartthrob extload.php error 403

Tags: cartthrob, error

I have an old store EE 2.5.3, CT 2.2.9 - implementation from 2012. A week ago, I get this message overnight when returning from the payment gateway to the cartthrob store. [403] Forbidden /themes/third_party/cartthrob/lib/extload.php/przelewy24/success. Has anyone encountered this? Maybe the server settings have been changed? The extload.php file has 755 permissions. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think something changed on either the hosting or on the payment gateway side. Not very strange when a site runs on this old software versions

Answer (score 0):

Apologize. Jelle is right. The hosting company changed security settings without notifying. Fortunately, we managed to turn it off.